# Why does passing a KerasTensor to Sequential.add not raise a TypeError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

In the [definition](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/engine/sequential.py#L42-L472) of `keras.Sequential.add`, we have (in accordance with the docs)

```
    if isinstance(layer, tf.Module):
      if not isinstance(layer, base_layer.Layer):
        layer = functional.ModuleWrapper(layer)
    else:
      raise TypeError('The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. '
                      f'Received: layer={layer} of type {type(layer)}.')
```

and yet, when I execute

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(100))
```

a `TypeError` is not raised. `keras.Input` returns a tensor, and the [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9334a8cc0cc5c54fc20b1efc386892a5e5db3656/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py#L40) of a `KerasTensor` shows that it inherits from an `Object`, and not a `Layer`.

Why can I add an `Input` to a `Sequential`, rather than being required to add an `InputLayer` as I would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/engine/sequential.py#L166), we read:

> If we are passed a Keras tensor created by keras.Input(), we can
> extract the input layer from its keras history and use that without any loss of generality.

It seems like `keras.Input` is being internally converted into an `InputLayer` [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/engine/sequential.py#L169):

```
    if hasattr(layer, '_keras_history'):
      origin_layer = layer._keras_history[0]
      if isinstance(origin_layer, input_layer.InputLayer):
        layer = origin_layer
```

This can also be verified with this snippet:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(100)
print(inputs._keras_history[0])
```

```
<keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f9379a0cdd0>
```

And that is the reason you are not seeing any errors.

Comment: Yes, it does. Accepted. Thank you. The docs for `Sequential.add` say `Raises: TypeError: If 'layer' is not a layer instance.` Do you think this warrants a correction?

Comment: It is definitely not entirely clear that `keras.Input`, which is a `KerasTensor`, is converted internally into a `InputLayer`. So, maybe not a correction but an extension.